# Take too much time to preload assets?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making a puzzle game, it has over 200 images with cost 4 Mbs. I use AssetManager to load it in game start. But it took me 7 seconds to complete is too long. If I use TexturePacker, will it faster ? Does anyone has idea about it ?
Thanks.

Comment: did you try to get your images from asset using asyncTask in background

Comment: yeah, I did it in background. I intent to make a process bar, waiting 7 seconds is too long for users. Or, I will disable preload assets, just create it when they need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, packing your images into an atlas will make loading them faster. Furthermore, it will make your game run better as well. Of course, the exact gain depends on the number of images, size of the images, number of pages, size of pages, device tested on, and so forth.

Note that AssetManager already loads in the background what can be loaded in the background, you dont have to do that yourself.

Comment: thank @Xoppa, I decide get rid of AssetManager, just create it when needed,

Comment: I'm not sure how this comment relates to your question. Please note that not using AssetManager is not an answer to your question. Also note that AssetManager already allows you to load assets when needed, you dont have to get rid of it for that.